# Created a yammer group a day ago and still not showing up in API

Tags: yammer

I just started doing some yammer-to-website integration using their API's to get the feed of a particular group.

I recently added 6 new groups and trying to get these through the Javascript API ***(requirement i know i can hardcode them as i have their Id's)*** but one thing I've noticed is that its been a day already and the following rest endpoint is still not returning me those new groups I created.

**Endpoint is** 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json

The group was set as public (by default) is there anything else i would have to do in order to get these new groups as part of my response?

the funny thing is when i do the following call for the groups i currently belong to

**Endpoint:**
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1 
they show up here?

Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: How many groups are there? Maybe you need to page forward?

Comment: theres 50 groups in my response... hmmm paged aye but its the groups.json, should'nt it return all? didnt know theres a paging parameter for that one...